# How can I get the full path of my selected file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, import, spreadsheet

I have put a `file_field` in my view :

```
<% form_for(:uploaded_file, @feed, :url => {:action=>'copy'}, :html=> {:multipart=>true}) do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %> <br>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And I have a method in my controller that reads a Excel file:

```
def copy
    file = ""
    book = Spreadsheet.open 'excel_file'
    table = book.worksheet 'excel_sheet'
    table.each do |row|
      file << row
    end
end
```

Log with request

```
"authenticity_token"=>"BbQRomTLhiF2O54/G6eHwnnaWbLttUSvo31FO3ZtKoA=", 
"uploaded_file"=>{"uploaded_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:
 0x27b7ab‌​0 @original_filename="test.xlsx",@content_type="application
 /vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", @headers=
 "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file[uploaded_file]\";
 filename=\"volumetrie.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats
 officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/DOCUME~1/me/
 LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110714-524-fy6vu>>}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I'm just trying to get the path of my selected file to insert it in my Spreadsheet.open method. The error message is : No such file or directory.

Instead of `'excel_file'` that is the path of my Excel file, I would like to use the path of the file that I have choosed in the `file_field` in my view. How can I use this parameter ?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you mean the full location of the file on the server, or the full location of the file on the user's machine? Because you can't get that information about the user's machine

Comment: On the user's machine, but, if I can't do it that way, how does the user can choose a xls file to be read and appended in the database ? (without requiring the path)

Comment: Oh, the user *can* choose a file using their browser's file-chooser dialog, but all *you* get sent to the server is the filename and the file contents

Comment: The file content is the parameter `:uploaded_file` ? Or it is something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get path to file from form in modern browsers. You can work only with tempfile Should be available as `params[ :uploaded_file ][ :tempfile ]`

**Edit** try

```
file = Spreadshet::Excel.new('params[ :uploaded_file ][ :filename ]', 'w+')
file.write( params[ :uploaded_file ][ :tempfile ].read )
```

Comment: Sorry I am really new to Rails, I'm just trying to get the path of my selected file to insert it in my `Spreadsheet.open` method...

Comment: Ok. I've tried many different things and I do not find out the problem. I always have this error message afer doing what you told me.
`undefined method 'new' for Spreadsheet:Module`
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

File.absolute_path(file)

[Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000023)

Comment: Where do I use the parameters with that ?